# Hibernate - Transactions : Consistency between two Accounts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to maintain consistency between transactions in Hibernate, for example, I have this kind of scenario -

I have two transactions, `T1` & `T2`,
both are simultaneously operating on same account `A`(initial value = `500`),
`T1` wants to make `200` addition and `T2` wants to minus `100` from `A`.
If transaction happens like this -

```
1. T1 reads value of A as 500, T2 reads value of A as 500.
2. T1 does A = 500 + 200.
3. T2 does A = 500 -100.
4. T2 commits value of A as 400.
5. T1 commits Value of A as 700.
```

The final value of `A` will be `700`, which is **incorrect**. **The correct value of `A` should be `600`.**

How this can be fixed?

- A = Account, means a Tuple i.e a Row in a RDBMS table. Here, it represent a Bank Account which Uniquely Identified by an Account Number.

Comment: take a look at locking strategies (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/locking/Locking.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you two strategies.

The first one is Optimistic Locking. It allows you to detect this kind of situations and resolve them by failing the second transaction. This means

> T1 commits Value of A as 700.

results in `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`. To implement this strategy you should create special column in `A` entity representing version of the current Tuple and annotate it with `javax.persistence.Version`. After every commit Jpa provider will increment version column automatically and will check it value on every commit like this:

```
1. T1 reads value of A (v1) as 500, T2 reads value of A (v1) as 500 .
2. T1 does A = 500 + 200.
3. T2 does A = 500 -100.
4. T2 commits value of A as 400 - db and entity versions are the same
5. T1 commits Value of A (v1) as 700 - version mismatch: db version is v2 and current version is v1 -> OptimisticLockException
```

The second strategy is Pessimistic Locking (exclusive locking):
It allows the first transaction (T1 from your example) to lock Tuple from reading\writing it from the different transaction until it releases lock on commit\rollback. You can achieve this by calling `javax.persistence.EntityManager#lock` with `javax.persistence.LockModeType#WRITE` as the second argument.